# 'rails c -e production' uses wrong schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem using Rails `4.1.1` and `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` `1.5.4`.

I do not why, but when I use `rails c -e production`, the wrong schema is used. Some time ago, it works.

The productions server uses the correct schema, but I do not dare to restart it :-)

I do not set the `table_name`, or something else in the `Project` class.

Test with `rails c -e production`

```
Project.count
=> (7.5ms)  SELECT column_name AS name, data_type AS sql_type, data_default, nullable, virtual_column, hidden_column, data_type_owner AS sql_type_owner, DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER', data_precision, 'FLOAT', data_precision, 'VARCHAR2', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'RAW', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'CHAR', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), NULL) AS limit, DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER', data_scale, NULL) AS scale FROM all_tab_cols WHERE owner = 'USER_DEV' AND table_name = 'PROJECTS' AND hidden_column = 'NO' ORDER BY column_id
=> Sequence (0.8ms)  select us.sequence_name from all_sequences us where us.sequence_owner = 'USER_DEV' and us.sequence_name = 'PROJECTS_SEQ'
=> Primary Key (8.2ms)  SELECT cc.column_name FROM all_constraints c, all_cons_columns cc WHERE c.owner = 'USER_DEV' AND c.table_name = 'PROJECTS' AND c.constraint_type = 'P' AND cc.owner = c.owner AND cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
=> (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "PROJECTS"
=> 2


Rails.env
=> "production"

Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
=> {"adapter"=>"oracle_enhanced", "database"=>"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXX)))", "username"=>"USER", "password"=>"XXX"}
```

Test with `rails c`

```
Project.count
=> (9.4ms)  SELECT column_name AS name, data_type AS sql_type, data_default, nullable, virtual_column, hidden_column, data_type_owner AS sql_type_owner, DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER', data_precision, 'FLOAT', data_precision, 'VARCHAR2', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'RAW', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'CHAR', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), NULL) AS limit, DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER', data_scale, NULL) AS scale FROM all_tab_cols WHERE owner = 'USER_DEV' AND table_name = 'PROJECTS' AND hidden_column = 'NO' ORDER BY column_id
=> Sequence (0.8ms)  select us.sequence_name from all_sequences us where us.sequence_owner = 'USER_DEV' and us.sequence_name = 'PROJECTS_SEQ'
=> Primary Key (8.1ms)  SELECT cc.column_name FROM all_constraints c, all_cons_columns cc WHERE c.owner = 'USER_DEV' AND c.table_name = 'PROJECTS' AND c.constraint_type = 'P' AND cc.owner = c.owner AND cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
=> (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "PROJECTS"
=> 2

Rails.env
=> "development"

Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
=> {"adapter"=>"oracle_enhanced", "database"=>"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXX)))", "username"=>"USER_DEV", "password"=>"XXX"}
```

Comment: When you say "the wrong schema" do you mean that the console is using the development database when you run it in production mode?  Check your config/database.yml file and make sure the right database is set in the "production" entry there.

Comment: Our oracle database is using the user name as the schema. So in development, I use the user `USER_DEV`. The schema `USER_DEV` is used for the data.

In production, I use the user `USER` and the schema `User` will be used.

This worked for a long time. I did not make any changes to the `database.yml`

Answer (score 0):

`Spring` was the reason why the wrong Oracle database schema was used. Related to https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/305, e.g. `ENV` is not loaded correctly.

I added `puts Rails.env` to one of my initializers. It always says `development`, even if I use `rails c -e production`.

After running `bin/spring binstub --remove --all`, the correct schema was used.

By the way, all variables defined in the initializers having a different behavior for `development`, `test`, and `production`, were affected as well.